# mysql return TIMEDIFF between row in single table

Tags: mysql

in my app i a have an appointments that the users orders, and the table looks like that:

```
id simTypeID simID   simDateTime            startHour endHour  
1  100       1       2016-09-01 09:00:00  09:00:00  10:00:00 
2  100       2       2016-09-01 10:00:00  10:00:00  11:00:00 
3  100       3       2016-09-01 11:00:00  11:00:00  12:00:00 
4  100       1       2016-10-11 10:00:00  10:00:00  11:00:00
```

*note: start time is 09:00 AM everyday

now i want to get all the free time in **specific date** (for example 2016-09-01) by **simID**

it means that the result need to be in tbl_free_time:

```
simID  startFreeHour  endFreeHour
1      10:00:00       23:59:00
2      09:00:00       09:59:00
2      11:00:00       23:59:00
3      09:00:00       10:59:00
3      12:00:00       23:59:00
```

how can I use TIMEDIFF on the same table ? ( need to take endHour of first row and startHour of second row ).

any other way to solve this problem will be appreciated!

i was thinking to create temp tbl with:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_sim_temp LIKE tbl_sim

INSERT tbl_sim_temp 
SELECT * FROM tbl_sim 
WHERE simDateTime BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-01 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

and than to use **LEFT JOIN** , something like that-

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(a.startHour,b.endHour) 
FROM a tbl_sim 
LEFT JOIN b tbl_sim_temp 
WHERE a.simID = b.simID AND a.simTypeid = b.simtypeid AND a.id = b.id+1
```

but I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.

```
SELECT simID, startFreeHour, endFreeHour
FROM (
    SELECT simID, "09:00:00" as startFreeHour, SUBTIME(startHour, '00:01:00') as endFreeHour
    FROM tbl_sim 
    WHERE 
        startHour > "09:00:00"
        AND DATE(simDateTime) = "2016-09-01" 

    UNION 

    SELECT simID, endHour as startFreeHour, "23:59:00" as endFreeHour
    FROM tbl_sim 
    WHERE 
        endHour < "23:59:00"
        AND DATE(simDateTime) = "2016-09-01"
) as t1
ORDER BY simID ASC, startFreeHour ASC
```

It only works if there is only one row for day and simId and assuming that seconds will always be zero to limit to 23:59:00. So with this scenario will not work:

```
id simTypeID simID   simDateTime            startHour endHour  
1  100       1       2016-09-01 09:00:00  10:00:00  11:00:00 
1  100       1       2016-09-01 09:00:00  12:00:00  13:00:00
```

If this scenario is possible just tell me and I will try it again.

Comment: I don't understand, you can have in the same day two rows with the same simId?

Comment: yes. each simID works from 09:00 till 23:59 - so i can have many rows with the same simID in each day. but your solution working great

Comment: I've been trying but is quite complex, I think you would need a stored procedure to accomplish this, I totally advise you against using stored procedures as they are very difficult to debug and control. What language are you using to retrieve this info? implementing a function in php for example to accomplish this would be a lot more easy.